# Where is session.id in Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

With Play 1.0 we had the session.getId() method to retrieve a unique session identifier.

The id was handy to prefix keys in the global cache.

Where is Play 2.0 session.id equivalent ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the session data is stored as cookies, there is no more session id with play 2.0. In fact there is no need for an identify token either, the session data is just passed along with every request leaving the server completely stateless.

However, you may still need an id should you need to store per user data in the global cache.
For this purpose, use the code below

```
// Generate a unique id
String uuid=session("uuid");
if(uuid==null) {
    uuid=java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    session("uuid", uuid);
}
```

Session id? it sounds so Java EE anyways...

Comment: How do you control lifecycle of objects in the global cache? You configure TTLs and other expiration parameters ?

Comment: The lifecycle depends on the cache implementation. I don't know the details, if I recall EHCache uses WeakReferences which are cleared when the JVM requires memory. EHCache is one of the best api for caching, I am sure they support expiration settings.

Comment: Ok, but what is so fundamentally diffrent/better in Play 2.0 ? A session (in general) is just a store with a certain lifecycle. The "state trouble" is imho caused by implemenation details.

Comment: I only have 500 chars, but you should research about restful frameworks vs session based frameworks and their benefits when it comes to scalability. In regards to the cache, with j2ee if you do request.getSession().get("mykey"); the value is there for the lifetime of the session, typically 30mn or more depending on usage. In play the data might not be there when you get it from the cache... so you have to think about recreating the cache entry. In other words it's a real cache, not a j2ee session.

Comment: The scalabilty problem with typical (container dependent) JEE sessions is replication + change frequency, right ? The pro I see for the Play 2.0 approach so far is its independence of the container implementation.

Comment: might not be the right place to have these kind of discussion. we are way off topic. please submit any concerns to the play mailing list. sincerely

Comment: What if I want to store sensitive data in the session, like OAuth tokens?

Comment: the session cookie is ciphered.

Comment: If the session cookie is encrypted, with what key? How is the key generated / where is it stored?

Comment: server side. symmetric encryption - don't remember where is it - but recall you can change it from the play command line.